# how to get nearest place by lat long with radious in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table name "users" and i want to get nearest users (according to my current lat long) with radious(dynamic value),How can i do this ? Here is my table "users"
current lat -  30.739834
current lng -  76.782700
radious     -  7

```
id          lat                 lng                 city
1           30.71192000         76.79062000         sector 35 chandigarh
2           30.69845000         76.73083000         sector 8,mohali
3           30.65110000         76.82100000         zirakupr
4           30.16808500         77.29692100         Jagadhri    
5           19.99821100         73.76175700         sharanpur
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the [search feature](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+closest++longitude) on top of the page? While I am not entirely sure what you mean by "dynamic radious" (I assume you want to limit the search radius?), a good percentage of questions that contain the word "longitude" are asking about how to find the closest cities/users/shops/girlfriends/planets/jobs to some point.

Answer (score 0):

I had this solution before in my previous companies like 8 years ago.
Unfortunately I didnt have the copy of my formula. But I can still remember the "logic" I applied to it.

1. Make a class/function that will solve for **distance** for North, South,East, West directions.
2. Your class/function must have initial input Longitude and Latitude as starting point. It will serve as starting point of the measure.
3. Combine your calculated longitude and latitude imaginary,  North-west, north-east, south-west, south-east  data groups  and pair the conditions to the SQL syntax.

```
-------------------------------
|       NW     |      NE      |
|              |              |
-------------------------------
|              |              |
|       SW     |      SE      |
-------------------------------
```

It's not the much but I hope it helps.